# React Native With Expo: Web Browser not rendering images

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo

I am building an app with React Native. I have a <Image /> react native component that renders on android but doesn't seem to render on the browser. When inspecting the element, the browser has the image element with the size of 0x0.

I am using the expo-cli and created a fresh project with the following code (stripped out version of my code) to isolate the issue. It works for android but doesn't show an image for web.

Also, I tried it using https://snack.expo.io and it works for web there.

Is there something I am missing here?

Isolated Code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, Image, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
const source = require("./assets/icon.png");

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>test: </Text>
      <Image style={styles.image} source={source} />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    display: "flex",
    alignItems: "center",
    flexDirection: "row",
    height: "5%",
  },
  image: {
    resizeMode: "contain",
    maxHeight: "100%",
    flexShrink: 2,
    flexGrow: 0,
  }
});
```

Comment: can you try, giving height value to 200 or other value relevant to your image. height: 200 and remove maxHeight

Comment: The problem is I need the image to resize based on the container it is in.

Comment: can you check this - https://reactnative.dev/docs/image-style-props#resizemode

Comment: I am familiar with resize mode. I am using it currrently in the example given